# Start content after window height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate a design pattern I often see on webpages. I'd like the content of my page to start after the full height of the window.
I have a header with a bunch of links which are centered both vertically and horizontally in my screen and I would like the first paragraph not to be displayed on the page (you should scroll to see it, you should only see the header when you land on the page).
I've tried to apply a `margin-top:100%` to my content but it is way too far in the bottom of the page since the height of the header is added to the margin.
Schematically this would be something like this

```
<body>
<!-- You can see this when you load the page -->
<div id="header">
blablabla 
<a href="">Index</a>
<a href="">Contact</a>
<a href="">...</a>
</div>

<!-- You should scroll to see this -->
<div id="content">
<p>...</p>
</div>
</body>
```

In javascript this would like this :

```
var height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
var hheight = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("content").style.marginTop = (height - hheight)+ "px";
```

Any hints on how to do that? I often see these kind of patterns on mobile designs but I never figured out how to do it. I can do it using javascript, but I think there might be a way of doing it with pure css ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vh` units. `100vh` is the height of the viewport. Here's a reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body>
<!-- You can see this when you load the page -->
<div id="header">
blablabla 
<a href="">Index</a>
<a href="">Contact</a>
<a href="">...</a>
</div>

<!-- You should scroll to see this -->
<div id="content">
<p>...</p>
</div>
</body>
```